# How to exclude fields from Pydantic schema based on request query parameter in FastAPI?

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I would want to create a query parameter named `response_fields` which the frontend would use to specify which fields from the Pydantic schema class would they like to be returned. So, for example if the class is

```
class TestSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
```

I would like for them to be able to specify `...?response_fields=id` and the endpoint would only return the ID of it.

I've already tried using a Custom API Route class, however that seems to only be initialized  on start up and does not depend on the request. Is this a supported feature in FastAPI, or if not, any tips as to where should I look to hook this would be great.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I see the usefulness in this, but I would implement it by making all fields in the Pydantic schema `Optional` with `None` as default, and then use the [`response_model_exclude_unset` setting](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/?h=response#use-the-response_model_exclude_unset-parameter)

Comment: Depending on how you want the feature documented automagically, you could use a middleware that decodes the response, removes any unwanted fields and keeps the rest. That way you'd still get documentation that reflects the actual response and fields available, while filtering the response later. `response_fields` wouldn't be included in the documentation for each endpoint, however - but that depends on what your goal is when it comes to autogenerated docs.

Comment: @MatsLindh I wanted to try that but I just don't want to decode the response and encode it as it doesn't seem right. The documentation is not a problem though.